# null pointer exception while retrieving from firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception

Unable to fetch data from my database all permissions are public and dependencies included. I am trying to print data to logcat, receiving *NullPointerException*

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String co2=dataSnapshot.child("co2").getValue().toString();
                String humi=dataSnapshot.child("humi").getValue().toString();
                String temp=dataSnapshot.child("temp").getValue().toString();
                Log.i("kkk","hhh"+ co2 +" "+humi +" "+temp);
                // ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // Getting Post failed, log a message
                Log.w("p", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                // ...
            }
        });

    }
}
```

[image: **My db Structure**]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under your root reference, there are multiple objects. In order to get those objects, you need to iterate over the `DataSnapshot` object using `getChildren()` method, like in the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            double co2 = ds.child("co2").getValue(Double.class);
            long humi = ds.child("humi").getValue(String.class);
            long temp = ds.child("temp").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, co2 + " / " + humi + " / " + temp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in your logcat will be:

```
1007.87401... / 70 / 24
1259.84251... / 63 / 26
1511.81102... / 63 / 26
//The other records
```

Comment: Alex Mamo how did you figure this out any docs please share .I was unable to find this in documentation

Comment: Here are the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write). Regarding how could I figure this out, was to see that there more than one children under your root.